# .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How do I write a rewrite rule for the following condition.

1. I have my directory setup as
   /root/projectname/trunk/www/

I've setup site.local in hosts file to point to /root/

2. How do I make this request
   http://site.local/projectname to grab data from /root/project_name/trunk/www/ instead of from /root/projectname/ ?

Right now I have it as RewriteRule ^projectname/*$ projectname/trunk/www/ [L]
That works for just http://site.local/projectname, but others like http://site.local/projectname/images/image1.jpg doesn't work.

Please enlight.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write you rule like following

```
RewriteRule ^projectname/(*)$ projectname/trunk/www/$1 [L]
```

but not tested

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured out what's cracking.
Since the mapping and mapped path both contains projectname, it just keeps on rewriting.
So I got to change the name to something else and it works.

Thanks,
Tee